# Proper way of writing a HQL in ( ... ) query

Tags: hibernate, hql

Assuming that I want to write the following HQL query:

```
FROM Cat c WHERE c.id IN (1,2,3)
```

what is the proper way of writing this as a parametrized query, e.g.

```
FROM Cat c WHERE c.id IN (?)
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

I am unsure how to do this with positional parameter, but if you can use named parameters instead of positional, then named parameter can be placed inside brackets and [setParameterList](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection)) method from [Query](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Query.html) interface can be used to bind the list of values to this parameter.

```
...
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Cat c WHERE c.id IN (:ids)");
query.setParameterList("ids", listOfIds);
...
```

Answer (score 12):

Older versions of Hibernate may not have the `setParameterList` method on `Query`. You can still call `setParameter("ids", listOfIds);` on the older one for the same effect.

Comment: Why has this been changed anyways? Just spent an hour figuring out why `IllegalArgumentException in class: org.ase.mip.persistence.entities.BaseEntityImpl, getter method of property: id (BasicPropertyAccessor.java:186))` was happening. I called `setParameter` instead of `setParameterList`. DOH!

Answer (score -5):

Named parameters are better than positional parameters, we should be careful in looking at the order/position - while named is easy.

Named:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select count(*) from User"+" where userName=:userName and passWord=:passWord");
        query.setString("userName", userName);
        query.setString("passWord", passWord);
```

Positional:

```
Query query=em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.empId = ? and  e.empDepartment = ?");
query.setParameter(1, employeId);
query.setParameter(2, empDepartment);
```

Comment: Fully agree, but that does not answer my question about IN(...) queries