# Fetching sets of objects from GORM

Tags: grails, transactions, batch-file, grails-orm

I'm working on Grails.
At some point I have to fetch large sets of objects from the db, based on their ids.
If I do this id by id, the performance is very bad.

```
ids.each{
   Myclass.findById( id )
   ...
}
```

Given that for storing batches there's the useful **withTransaction** closure, is it possible to do something like that to fetch objects, instead of storing them?

Another idea could be a long HQL query like:

```
"select * from Myclass where (id = 1) OR ( id = 2) ... OR ( id = n )"
```

Is this an ok solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961816/proper-way-of-writing-a-hql-in-query), HQL supports a better syntax for selecting based on a group of values, which is supported by GORM's `find()` method. GORM [dynamic finders](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.4.1%20Dynamic%20Finders) would also support syntax like:

```
def myObjs = MyClass.findByIdInList(ids)
```

Similarly, if your operation is read-only, you could use `getAll()`, which will take advantage of the optimizations Hibernate can make for read-only transations.