# "IN" statement in play using hql

Tags: java, hql, playframework

How can I write an HQL query like same SQL query like this:

```
select * from Users u where u.id in (1, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961816/proper-way-of-writing-a-hql-in-query Another example using JPA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828049/in-clause-in-hql-or-java-persistence-query-language I've never used hql, but it always help to google a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `User.find("id in (:ids)").bind("ids", new Long[]{1L,3L,4L}).fetch()`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use native query to utilize your SQL query, so that you don't have to convert to HQL.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this with play is

```
public static void findByIds(List<Long> userIds) {
    find("from Users u where u.id in (?1)", userIds).fetch();
}
```